# Reading all values from certain tags in XML with Python 3

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have an XML structure like this

```
<city>
   <house>
       <color>red</color>
       <residents>3</residents>
   </house>
   <house>
       <color>yellow</color>
       <residents>5</residents>
   </house>
   <apartment>
       <color>blue</color>
       <residents>4</residents>
   </apartment>
</city>
```

What I am looking to do, is get the total population in this city that lives in houses - basically fetch all `residents` tags' values under the `house` tag.

Every solution I can find will get me all te `residents` and a sum of 12 instead of 8: which is the correct number.

I am also restricted to use minidom only ://

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Every solution I can find..." - What exactly have you tried so far? Being restricted to minidom only is a really strange requirement, btw.

Comment: Refer to xpath documentation for xpath examples https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=xpath and the `findall()` function https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=findall#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.findall

Answer (score 0):

See below. `'.//house/residents'` is the XPATH expression that does the magic.

**Note** that the solution is based on ElementTree (core python) and not minidom

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<city>
   <house>
       <color>red</color>
       <residents>3</residents>
   </house>
   <house>
       <color>yellow</color>
       <residents>5</residents>
   </house>
   <apartment>
       <color>blue</color>
       <residents>4</residents>
   </apartment>
</city>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(sum(int(r.text) for r in root.findall('.//house/residents')))
```

output

```
8
```

**minidom based solution**

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

xml = '''<city>
   <house>
       <color>red</color>
       <residents>3</residents>
   </house>
   <house>
       <color>yellow</color>
       <residents>5</residents>
   </house>
   <apartment>
       <color>blue</color>
       <residents>4</residents>
   </apartment>
</city>'''

residents = 0
dom = parseString(xml)
houses = dom.getElementsByTagName('house')
for h in houses:
    resident = h.getElementsByTagName('residents')
    residents += int(resident[0].firstChild.data)
print(residents)
```

output

```
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me also say: Being restricted to minidom only is a really strange requirement:)
Give you another solution for your reference.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc

xml = '''
<city>
   <house>
       <color>red</color>
       <residents>3</residents>
   </house>
   <house>
       <color>yellow</color>
       <residents>5</residents>
   </house>
   <apartment>
       <color>blue</color>
       <residents>4</residents>
   </apartment>
</city>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
residents = doc.selects('city>residents>text()')
print (sum(int(r) for r in residents))
```

Result:

```
12
```